# How can I run a Java 11 .jar file on Heroku in paralell with a Node.js app?

Tags: java, node.js, heroku, jar

I have a discord.js bot that's music system requires to run a .jar file (Lavalink). I didn't find anything about how to install Java 11 on Heroku. The bot is running perfectly on Heroku, I just need to figure out a way to run the Lavalink.jar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the JAR file is already present in our application and you only need to install Java 11 itself, you can add the `heroku/jvm` buildpack with `heroku buildpacks:add heroku/jvm`. To [specify your Java version](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#specifying-a-java-version), add a new file to the root of your application named `system.properties` with the following contents:

```
java.runtime.version=11
```

The next time your app is rebuilt, `java` will be available in your dyno.

Answer (score 0):

For application Java put the file in root folder of the project

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.